# Does it matter if I upgrade to w10 over a ropey w7 installation?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I just bought a new system, running w7 preinstalled.  I've had some teething troubles with it.  Mainly freezes and BSODS which appear to be due to driver problems or [possibly a bad KB update](https://superuser.com/questions/756346/lsa-lsasrv-the-security-package-kerberos-generated-an-exception-the-exceptio).

I've spent a couple of days trying to sort it out, but eventually I decided to NFO and do a clean install of w7.

But... then comes the upgrade to w10.

I might not bother reinstalling w7 and just jump to w10 instead.

Is it worth ensuring that my w7 installation is running smoothly before upgrading to 10?  Or will the 10 upgrade simply wipe out any problems with the previous installation?

Comment: To get the free copy of Windowd 10, you must have win 7 SP1 / 8.1 already installed.

Comment: It is installed and kosher, there's just a few bugs in there.  I wondered if the upgrade would iron those out

Comment: To be frank, there's more people reporting bugs with Windows 10 at the moment than Windows 7. Of course, YMMV.

Comment: I was going to leave the upgrade a few months, but the current w7 installation is virtually unusable, so thought I'd bite the bullet. If 10 gives me problems, I guess I can nuke it with 7 again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10 *can* inherit some of the problems with a previous installation depending on what option you choose during the install.

If you choose the "Keep nothing" option then it will wipe the existing install and will effectively be a "clean install". Of course, it won't wipe any hardware related issues.

Comment: Thank you.  I see there are 3 options: 1. Keep settings files and apps, 2. Keep files only  and 3.  Keep nothing.  So I shall select the second, then hopefully that will wipe the current install.

Comment: Yes, the second option should wipe the install but because it inherits *some* stuff it's not as reliable as a complete clean install (option 3 aka NFO).

Comment: I may try the nfo option in that case. It gives me a windows.old folder, so I can just copy the files over myself. Not bothered about user settings really.